# UnidecodeDecode when reading .txt file

Tags: python, decode, utf

This may be a very basic fix, but I've dived through every example online trying to sort this out. I'm loading in a text file with Python 3.4 like so:

```
text = open("/Users/Stu/python/extext.txt")
text = unidecode(text)
text = open(text, "r").read()
```

and then I get thrown this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Stu/Twitter Python/Victoria.py", line 46, in <module>
    short_pos = unidecode(short_pos)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/unidecode/__init__.py", line 37, in unidecode
    for char in string:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 4645: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm assuming that it's finding a character that it can't decode, but all there is in this doc is english and basic punctuation. Any support you guys could give would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Why are you trying to apply `unidecode()` on the *filename*? And what is the *full* traceback of your exception; you only gave us the last 3 lines.

Comment: @martijnPieters Apologies, edits made above. I'm new to this so please excuse any basic errors. I've also included the full traceback of exception.

Comment: What are you calling `unidecode` on?

Comment: Please post a short, complete, runnable program that produces the error message you are seeing. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: it turns out that it was "latin-1" encoded. I'm unsure why this was the case, but I seem to be having a lot of encoding issues on when using mac on both python and r. will have to look further into this. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: So `encoding="latin-1"` worked?

Comment: Yes, encoding="latin-1" allowed me to print the text

Comment: You can add and accept your own answer  then ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks for that. Getting used to the system still :)

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to allow me to read the text:

```
short_pos = open("/Users/Stu/Twitter Python/short_reviews/positive1.txt","r", encoding = "latin-1").read()
```

Thanks for everyone's support!